# Coturn server's relay canditates are present on Chromium but not on Firefox

Tags: webrtc, coturn

I have a coturn server running on a linode instance with the following config:

```
# listening-ip=private ip
external-ip=public ip
tls-listening-port=5349
listening-port=3478
min-port=10000
max-port=65535

user=something:something
realm=domain.online
lt-cred-mech

pkey=/path/privkey.pem
cert=/path/fullchain.pem

fingerprint
log-file=stdout
verbose

TURNSERVER_ENABLED=1
```

When I try to test my coturn server on this site https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
everything works fine on chromium 122.0.6261.57:

[chromium example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHTk1.png)

but on firefox 123.0 the relay does not work:

[firefox example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFNaq.png)

Any ideas why this happens?

I have checked that the public ip is correct and tried adding a listening-ip property but nothing changed.

Comment: To get a better understanding you could take a network trace (e.g. with Wireshark) while the application running on Firefox is interacting with the TURN server. That will show 1. whether the application is interacting with the TURN server (STUN binding requests and TURN Allocate requests) and 2. what the TURN server is responding (e.g. an error when asking for a CreatePermission). Sharing the capture file (properly sanitised from public IP addresses to protect your privacy) could give people like me the opportunity to help with the investigation.